# Segmentation fault when launching .NET Core app on Debian

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, segmentation-fault

Everything's in the title, if I try to **dotnet run** it exits with no message, however using **dotnet exec** on the DLL outputs "segmentation fault" and exits.

Comment: Which debian version you have? Also, have you tried it in debug mode on debian to see if any message is shown with dotnet run?

Comment: Also, the exec function is not supposed to be called directly by the user, look at the last entry on this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2243

Comment: Linux aam-srv 4.5.7-std-3 #1 SMP Tue Jul 12 09:56:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: dotnet run quits anyway

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so another developer working on the project found the problem. I caused a stack overflow (how convenient) on one of the custom attributes I made. Here's the code:

```
private string Message
{
    get
    {
        return this.Message;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Message = value;
    }
}
```

So basically, it was calling itself indefinitely. What I was supposed to do instead was create a second string to access it from:

```
private string Message
{
    get
    {
        return this.message;
    }
    set
    {
        this.message = value;
    }
}

private string message;
```

Hope it helps some of you!